# Implicit Function Theorem Conclusion

Tags: real-analysis, functions, implicit-function-theorem

According to [Implicit Function Theorem Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)

it has been said : **The implicit function theorem says that if $Y$ is an invertible matrix, then there are $U$, $V$, and $g$ as desired.**
How is the bold statement exactly concluded?

Comment: Are you asking for the *proof* of the theorem?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The "bold statement" seems about right to me

Comment: Yeah, simply I'm looking for a better stated proof.

Comment: @Dalamar Why does it seem right to you?!

Comment: That's not a proof, that's a "moral" statement to help you understand the "intention" of the theorem. The internet is just awash with actual proofs of Dini's theorem.

Comment: At least you could give one of the million resources you know on the internet, don't answer the questions by making generalities.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433283/better-proofs-than-rudins-for-the-inverse-and-implicit-function-theorems
You could also download Loomis-Sternberg Advanced calculus. It's free and it's a great book.